# How to change the shape of the Textview using themes and styles?

Tags: android, textview, shapes, android-theme

Is there any possible ways to change the shape of the TextView using themes and styles?

I have changed textview shape as rectangle but I failed to change the hexagonal shape of textview. How could I do this?

So far tried searching the web and tried the code, but got no solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources> 
    <style name="black_text_view_medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
            <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

This is the resource file make in the res/values/red.xml and define this style in your textview like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    style="@style/black_text_view_medium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="This is your Textview Style"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

shape.xml  ( save this in res/drawable/ )

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>        
<shape>
  <corners android:radius="3dp/>
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then Change background of TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/shape" />
```